# OPening user prefs Crashes blender

Tags: customization

So I had this problem when opening user prefs (creating a new window) blender immediately crashes. It doesnt crash if I just change a panel to user prefs. 
I was overdue on maintainence, so I reinstalled windows clean installs  all round.  And despite that its still knackered. I read about changing the intel vga drivers butnot sure that applies as I run GPU's not on chip graphics... Any help appreciated. 
heres the sys info 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi88sqixfg9f1la/system-info.txt?dl=0

Comment: This used to happen in some laptops with dual GPUs with integrated Intel graphics card and a discrete AMD GPU. It was caused by some driver bug solvable by installing a more recent version. Bad news is most manufacturers used specific proprietary drivers, and no newer versions were ever made available.

Comment: In keeping with your idea, I disabled one GPU and Itnow works... of course this meeans i have half the GPU's for rendering  Can't seem tofind a more permanant fix